# SQL select the available rooms by date cheking

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have in my database a table called rooms that contain the rooms information and property ,and another table called reservation table that contain the Room Reserved, FromDate and ToDate .

What i want to do is to make the user pick room size that he want to reserve and pick the date for reserving the room ,then i provide for him the available rooms depend on the Room Reservation table.

here what i did:

```
SELECT  * FROM Rooms,Reservations WHERE 
Rooms.R_Size = 'roomSize' AND ('4/19/2013' NOT 
BETWEEN Reservation.FromDate AND Reservation.ToDate  AND '4/19/2013'
NOT BETWEEN Reservation.FromDate AND Reservation.ToDate)
```

The problem its return to me duplicate's rooms and even if its between the reserved date in specific reservation but its not between reserved date in another reservation still it will return it to me.

What i want is to check if the room is reserved at the same or between a specif date and if it is i don't want it to be selected and returned at all.

Thanks.. and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your query. One is that there is no condition on the join between rooms and reservations, such that rooms of the correct size will be returned once for each reservation satisfying the date tests. Another problem is that your date test is wrong as it will not detect existing reservations that is completely within the date interval of the new reservation.

A query like this one should give you the result you want:

```
SELECT * FROM Rooms
LEFT JOIN Reservations 
ON Reservations.R_Number = Rooms.Number
AND Reservations.ToDate > '4/19/2013'
AND Reservations.FromDate < '4/20/2013'
WHERE Rooms.R_Size = 'roomSize' 
AND Reservations.R_Number IS NULL
```

It works by joining the rooms to the reservations for that room, and then selecting the rooms for which there are no reservations that conflicts with the new reservation being made.(Old reservation that ends before the new one starts, or that starts after the new one ends are no problem).

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here is a cross join. Every row from table a (Rooms) is joined with every row in table b (Reservations).

In order to make your query work, you need to specify that Rooms.Rooms_Key = Reservations.Rooms_ForignKey in your where clause (or an explicit join [inner,left,right] and specify the ON fields as they are easier to read in my opinion - [explicit-vs-implicit](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/databasedesign/thread/df27b6ba-3bd3-4a60-b2ab-b72a5f3e28b8/)  for more info).

Once you have converted the join type, the where clause will start to give you better results, and you should be able to modify it if you still need to at that point.