# Count the quantity of available rooms between two dates

Tags: mysql, .net, sql

I have two data tables:

- `tbroom_capacity`: `roomtype`, `quantity_room`, `note`

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `tbroom_capacity` (
      `id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `roomtype` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
      `quantity_room` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `note` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
  ```

data:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50542216/1.png

- `tbbooking`: `guestid`, `roomtypeid`, `quantity_room_booking`, `startDate`, `endDate`

  ```
  CREATE TABLE `tbbooking` (
      `guestid` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `roomtypeid` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
      `quantity_room_booking` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `startDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `endDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
  ```

data:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50542216/2.png

I want to calculate the remaining number of rooms between two dates with every room-type.

An example:

Total 15 room with 3 type: 10 standard, 2 superior, 3 VIP

- Guest 1: 3 standard from 2013-05-26 to 2013-05-27
- Guest 2: 3 standard from 2013-05-27 to 2013-05-28
- Guest 3 want to booking room from 2013-05-26 to 2013-05-28

I tried this to retrieve the total unavailable rooms:

```
SELECT sum(quantity_room_booking) FROM tbbooking 
where DATE_ADD(endDate,INTERVAL -1 DAY) >= '2013-05-26' 
and startDate <= '2013-05-28' GROUP BY roomtypeid
```

But the result is:

- **6** standard
- 2 superior
- 3 VIP

The result should be:

- **3** standard
- 2 superior
- 3 VIP

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: show your table structure and some sample data to save everyone some time

Comment: @DrewPierce: I have add my structure data, please help me. Thank you!

Comment: ok can u provide a little sample data

Comment: you are going to need to explain this a little. in tbbooking, since id is a primary key, it certainly does not relate back to tbroom_capacity.id. it looks almost as if tbroom is showing a room id and the quantity_room means how many people can stay there for a nite. and tbbooking is not an actual book (because it does not related to a particular room) but rather a booking request for start and end and # of guests, and desired room type

Comment: so i think what you are saying is that a customer calls up, and says I want a room from 6/1/2013 thru 6/3/2013 (3 nites avail), and we have a party of 3. what rooms do you have ? but you have to do the legwork on presenting this information (or whatever you are looking for) to people so they can simply answer it without leaving frustrated because it completely lacks info for them to help

Comment: @DrewPierce: yes, tbbooking doesn't relate to a particular room because i want manage room with amount. It's problem. Do you have some way to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: i can but i have to guess at sample data because 7 hrs later you havent provided any

Comment: @DrewPierce: i am sorry for late and i have updated my data, please help me.

Comment: show me via sqlfiddle or someplace the data loaded up and i can help. i am yet to see it. maybe we can chat tomorrow

Comment: Looking at Guest 1 and 2's bookings it look likes it does not have booking beyond 2013-05-28 which your query indicates specially the end date which means no bookings would match your query. Could you provide a sample data in your bookings table?

Comment: oh, i have mistaken on edit, the date is from 2013-05-26 to 2013-05-28. when i run my sql it return result 6 standard room instead of 3 as I count. i have edited and post my sample data with link from dropbox (i can't post image in here). please see and help me!

Comment: I wonder which school system is teaching using rooms and reservations: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3846182/62576, http://stackoverflow.com/q/16071372/62576

Comment: @Ken white: This is true if using with name of room but in our project, i want it show with amont of roomtype not room number.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more Boolean  column like Is booked and query the value using that column value

Example:

SELECT sum(quantity_room_booking) FROM tbbooking 
where DATE_ADD(endDate,INTERVAL -1 DAY) >= '2013-05-26' 
and startDate <= '2013-05-28' and Is booked=true GROUP BY roomtypeid

I hope this will help you to get the amount of room type